# How to avoid nested for loop for arraylist, java

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist

I have two arraylist , based on certain equality criteria i am setting values to one list,
below is the code , how to avoid nested for loop, how to optimize operation using map or any other way ,

```
ArrayList<TriggerTerm> triggerTerms = triggerDaoImpl.getTriggerTerm(.....);
ArrayList<Term> terms = baseDaoImpl.getTerm(.....);

for (TriggerTerm tt : triggerTerms) {
    for (Term t : terms) {
        if (tt.getCodeNumber().equals(t.getCodeNumber()) &&
            tt.getTermNumber().equals(t.getTermNumber())) {
            tt.setStartDate(t.getStartDate());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could place a `break;` after `tt.setStartDate(t.getStartDate());`, unless you specifically want to set the start date of the last matching `Term` in the list.

Comment: What's the relationship between `Term` and `TriggerTerm` classes?

Comment: You seem to be getting these two lists from a database. You can create an SQL view using a JOIN clause, and then you'll have just one loop.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest if we can make `is a` relationship between `Term` and `TriggerTerm` class (Seems it would be), it should be like this;

```
class Terms {

    private String codeNumber;

    private String termNumber;

    private String startDate;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Terms)) return false;

        Terms terms = (Terms) o;
        if (!codeNumber.equals(terms.codeNumber)) return false;
        return termNumber.equals(terms.termNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = codeNumber.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + termNumber.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}

class TriggerTerms extends Terms {
    // Inherit setters and getters from the super class as well as `equals` and `hashCode` function.
}
```

I've omitted getters and setters from the code. Also, please not the `equals` and `hashCode` implementation. I've only used `codeNumber` and `termNumber` variables.

If there are no duplicate values in both `triggerTerms` and `terms` lists, use `java.util.HashSet` rather than a `List`. Because following example I'm using `contains()` function. In `ArrayList` time complexity of `contains()` implementation is `O(n)` as well as the `indexOf()`, but in `HashSet` it's `O(1)` thanks to its implementation. If you use

So, simply use following code snippet;

```
for (TriggerTerms tt : triggerTerms)  {
    if (terms.contains(tt)) {
        tt.setStartDate(terms.get(terms.indexOf(tt)).getStartDate());
    }
}
```